# Problem printing from acrordrdc via cups

Tags: printing

Attempting to print from acrordrdc via CUPS to a printer served by another host fails
with a message in the cups error log:

```
Unsupported raster data.
```

The print job hangs, though it appears that the client CUPS daemon and the host CUPS daemon appear to be talking to each other.  I can print the same pdf via the document viewer from the client without any problems.  I can also print that document from acrordrdc on the host without any problems.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, 20.04 on both the client (laptop) and host (an old HP tower system).  I'll also note that  the same printing problem with the old Acroread Version 9 also installed on the laptop.  This is smelling like some kind of a problem with a filter being used by the Adobe apps.

Comment: I have more or less solved this issue.  The problem was with the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file on client where  <br/> <pre><code> BrowseLocalProtocols  <br/> was changed to  <br/><pre><code> BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd  <br/>  Don't know if/when/how this was changed.  In any case, acrordrdc now appears to print without any problems.  One point of confusion is that an entry for the printer pops up in the settings:printer page without any known location.

Comment: Another curiosity is that the document view will not print double sided with the printer set up via dnssd (Device URL dnssd://...).  However if I setup the printer by locating it using the printer host's IP address (Device URL ipp://Host ip address/...  the document viewer will complain about a conflict when setting double sided printing with the printer, but will print double sided anyway.